# ZF2: Zend Framework 2.0.3 (Routing Not Working - Controller Not Found)

Tags: zend-framework2

I setup a demo project and got routing to work between 2 different modules. However on my real application, having the Application module and a Restful module, my restful module router picks up but the controller cannot be found.

I am accessing it like `localhost/restful/token/json/1`

In my `Module.php` I have an onDispatch which I am using to dump the RouteMatch and I can see my route is actually being picked up.

`$mvcEvent->getRouteMatch()`

```
object(Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch)#185 (3) {
  ["length":protected]=>
  int(19)
  ["params":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(5) "token"
    ["format"]=>
    string(4) "json"
  }
  ["matchedRouteName":protected]=>
  string(7) "restful"
}
```

When Zend is trying to load the controller, it is merely passing `token` to the `DispatchListener::get` and through all the parents until it finally throws an exception that it cannot load the controller. Specifically, the final exception gets thrown in `DispatchLister::onDispatch` with `$application::ERROR_CONTROLLER_NOT_FOUND`.

The root exception being thrown is:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for "token".
```

`Stack Trace:`

```
#0 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(110): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('token', false)
#1 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/ControllerManager.php(114): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('token', Array, false)
#2 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(90): Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager->get('token')
#3 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(208): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(297): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/EMRAuth/public/index.php(22): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#8 {main}
```

I did the same dump in the `Application` module and it is actually passing the full namespaced controller name. As well in my demo project, in the extra module it is doing the same.

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this new project, but everything looks the same as my demo project. But its always just passing into the DispatchListener "token" instead of the actual controller.

`module.config.php`

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Restful\Controller\Token' => 'Restful\Controller\TokenController'
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'restful' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/restful[/:controller[/:format][/:id]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'format' => '(xml|json|sphp)',
                    'id' => '[1-9][0-9]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Restful\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Restful\Controller\Token',
                    'format' => 'json',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'dispatcher' => 'Restful\Response\Dispatcher',
        ),
        'Restful\Response\Dispatcher' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'options' => include(__DIR__ . '/dispatcher.config.php')
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

`Module.php`

```
namespace Restful;

use Zend\EventManager\StaticEventManager;

class Module
{

protected static $options;

public function init(\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{
    $events = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
    $events->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\RestfulController','dispatch', array($this, 'onDispatch'), -100);
    $events->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application','dispatch.error', array($this, 'onDispatch'),-100);
}

public function getConfig() {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $result = $mvcEvent->getResult();
    var_dump($mvcEvent->getRouteMatch());
    if ($mvcEvent->isError())
    {
        $vars = $result->getVariables();
        $errorId = $vars->offsetGet('reason');
        $errorMessage=$vars->offsetGet('message');
        $content = array(
            'error' => (is_null($errorId)) ? 'notfound-error' : $errorId,
            'message' => $errorMessage,
        );

    } else {
        $content = array(
            'content' => (is_array($result)) ? $result : $result->getVariables(),
        );
    }

    $match = $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch();
    $format = (empty($match)) ? 'json' : strtolower($mvcEvent->getRouteMatch()->getParam('format'));

    $dispatcher = $mvcEvent->getTarget()->getServiceManager()->get('dispatcher');

    return $dispatcher->render($format, $content, $mvcEvent->getResponse());
}

}
```

`TokenController.php`

```
namespace Restful\Controller;

class TokenController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController
{
public function getList()
{
    return array(
        1 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Title #1',
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Title #2',
        ),
    );
}

public function get($id)
{
    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => 'Title #1',
    );
}

public function create($data)
{

}

public function update($id, $data)
{

}

public function delete($id)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you defined parameter `:controller` in your route, which supersede default controller you specified.
Change your route definition to `'/restful[/token[/:format][/:id]]'`

As unrelated note: you must not specify data format as part of resource uri in RESTful API, pass it as get paramater `?format=xml` or use proper content negotiation mechanism in HTTP protocol.
Good HTTP header implementation in zf2 should help you in that.